# Architecture solution to flag variable

Tags: java, android, flags

After a long days of development, my class has become full of state variables. For example, I need to put a flag to wait until the view is back before proceed anything. So I wonder if you guys have any good or best practice to maintain these kind of states?

```
private BroadcastReceiver mClearJobReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (isResumed()) {
            mPresenter.clearJob();
        } else {
            mNeedToClearJob = true;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mNeedToClearJob) {
        mPresenter.clearJob();
        mNeedToClearJob = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elobarate your question by posting your code and explaining

Comment: It rather depends on what you're trying to do.  I'd suggest you [edit] your question to include a specific use case of trying to do something and how/why you use a flag to do it.

Comment: @azurefrog: I have provided the code

Comment: @Umarov: Please check again

Answer (score 0):

In general, when one is faced with flag variables, one should generally consider the application of the  *State Design Pattern*. This pattern is

> used to encapsulate varying behavior for the same object based upon its internal state. [Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Nystrom, in *Game Programming Patterns* (2014) noted that, "complex branching and mutable state -- fields that change over time -- are two...error prone types of code", and specifically recommends the State Pattern as an approach to resolving the situation. The essence of the OP's question is essentially this issue -- branching on mutuable states (with multiple `if` statements).

There is not enough code in the OP's question to provide a detailed recommended code solution. Nonetheless, the general approach is the definition of an interface and a class for each state implementing said interface. There should be sufficient guidance on the web in general, and SO in particular, to allow for an implementation.